# seeking for a general strategy to identify the right space for the domain of semigroup generator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, semigroup-of-operators

I wish to show the domain of a strongly continuous semigroup  $S(t)$ is some sobolev space, for instance, for the heat semigroup, it is known that
$$D(A)=W^{2,p}$$

I believe a general strategy to get above would be to show 
    $$D(A)\subseteq W^{2,p},$$
            and
    $$W^{2,p}\subseteq D(A) $$
However I am uncertain about how to achieve the above in detail, would be appreciate if anyone could outline me some steps to prove things like $D(A)=W^{2,p}.$